# Gstreamer 1.0 error: Missing element: HTTP protocol source

Tags: gstreamer

I have installed gstreamer 1.0 with base, good, ugly and bad plugin. When I run following command using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin     uri=http://-somr url to video src-
```

It gives me following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
Missing element: HTTP protocol source
ERROR: from element /GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: No URI handler   implemented for "http".
Additional debug info:
gsturidecodebin.c(1416): gen_source_element (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I am new to this and found most solution for gstreamer-0.10 which doesnot work for me. btw I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Badly looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing element: HTTP protocol source

And

```
 no_source:
  {
    /* whoops, could not create the source element, dig a little deeper to
     * figure out what might be wrong. */
    if (err != NULL && err->code == GST_URI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL) {
      gchar *prot;

      prot = gst_uri_get_protocol (decoder->uri);
      if (prot == NULL)
        goto invalid_uri;

      gst_element_post_message (GST_ELEMENT_CAST (decoder),
          gst_missing_uri_source_message_new (GST_ELEMENT (decoder), prot));

      GST_ELEMENT_ERROR (decoder, CORE, MISSING_PLUGIN,
          (_("No URI handler implemented for \"%s\"."), prot), (NULL));

      g_free (prot);
    } else {
      GST_ELEMENT_ERROR (decoder, RESOURCE, NOT_FOUND,
          ("%s", (err) ? err->message : "URI was not accepted by any element"),
          ("No element accepted URI '%s'", decoder->uri));
    }

    g_clear_error (&err);
    return NULL;
  }
```

Mean your gstreamer install has problem, you miss http client source plugin. Try `gst-inspect-1.0 souphttpsrc`? If no result, try to re-install plugin-good.

Comment: Actually the problem was installation. Some plugins are not compiled during  make if you don't have their dependencies installed. After running autogen.sh you have to check which plugins are installed and which are not. Again thanks cxphong for comment.